# Ripple color on ImageCardView in Android TV

Tags: android, material-design, android-tv, leanback

I am using the Leanback library for an Android TV application, and I am using the typical BrowseFragment that uses [ImageCardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ImageCardView.html)s for navigation. The ImageCardViews show a ripple effect when clicked: a semi-opaque white circle starts in the middle and grows to fill the View.

I am trying to change the ripple color to match my app's primary color. My application uses a custom Theme that inherits from Theme.Leanback, and I thought (based on e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31922339/925478) that I could change the ripple color by overriding the `colorControlHighlight` attribute in the theme:

```
<style name="MyLeanback" parent="Theme.Leanback">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

However, this does not seem to have any effect. When I click and hold an ImageCardView, I still see the semi-opaque white circle.

How can I change the color of the ripple?

Comment: Have you tried the other solution in the SO link that you provide?

Comment: @KENdi I found my answer as I was gearing up to try the other (runtime) solution. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was maddeningly easy:

```
<style name="MyLeanback" parent="Theme.Leanback">
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Note the `android:` prefix, which is required to override themes when not using `AppCompat`.

I had been dissuaded by the editor from including that prefix; it complained that it requires API21 (my application targets a lower version because it is a single .APK for mobile and TV platforms).