# Correctly setting the background of a list item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listitem, rippledrawable

I use a `RecyclerView` and a simple item layout consisting of a `ConstraintLayout` holding the text elements of each item. I want to set the background of all items while

1. showing a ripple effect when clicked.
2. visualizing when the view is *active*.
3. being able to set the colors. (optional, if it really has to be)

The minimum SDK version is 21 and is allowed to be raised if required.

---

What I tried:

- Using `@android:drawable/list_selector_background` is not customizable and did not show a ripple.
- Using `?selectableItemBackground` or `?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` does not work, it throws an exception at runtime (`Failed to resolve attribute [...]`). I do have the design support library placed in my gradle script, or now the `com.google.android.material` package. Prepending `android:attr/` produced the same error.
- Using a `StateListDrawable` to build it all by myself using many `<ripple>` Drawables seemed overly complicated since I did not want to reproduce the whole functionality of above features.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30556964/6287910

Comment: This seems to be part of a suitable solution. I will give it a try and report back. Getting `?selectableItemBackground` to work would be nicer though.

Comment: It looks like `?selectableItemBackground` can work by setting a style attribute. The same link I gave you tells you how. I didn't mention this because you seem to want several different colors to be available. This would changes the color, but it would still be just one color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31922339/3753684) linked by [@Cheticamp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6287910/cheticamp) combined with the approach in [this article](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/statelistdrawables-for-recyclerview-selection/) worked fine:

The layout of an item looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_background_active_handler">

    <include
        layout="@layout/the_actual_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackground" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And the `list_item_background_active_handler` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/listBackgroundActive" android:state_activated="true" />

    <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

This allows for handling the active state with a custom color. Simply call `isActivated(true)` on the view of an item in `onBindViewHolder()` in the adapter.

The color of the ripple effect can be customized with [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31922339/3753684).